# Why does plot(Vectorize(function)) work but curve(Vectorize(function)) does not?

Tags: r

Why does `plot(Vectorize(f))`, where `f` is a function, work, but `curve(Vectorize(f))` does not? This inconsistency bothers me a bit. Here is a full reproducable example:

```
set.seed(123)
N <- 9
X <- rnorm(N)
a <- 0.2
b <- 0.8
sigma <- 0.7
eps <- rnorm(N, 0, sigma)
Y <- a + b * X + eps


cor_p_value <- function(new_Y1)
{
Y[1] <- new_Y1
cor.test(X,Y)$p.value
}

lm_F_p_value <- function(new_Y1)
{
Y[1] <- new_Y1
anova(lm(Y ~ X))$Pr[1]
}

plot(Vectorize(cor_p_value), xlim = c(-50,50), lwd = 3)
curve(Vectorize(lm_F_p_value), col = "red", lwd = 3, lty = 2, add = TRUE)
# Error in curve(Vectorize(lm_F_p_value), col = "red", lwd = 3, lty = 2,  : 
# 'expr' must be a function, or a call or an expression containing 'x'
```

So for `curve`, I must do this annoying workaround:

```
cu <- Vectorize(lm_F_p_value)
curve(cu, col = "red", lwd = 3, lty = 2, add = TRUE)
```

But why? `Vectorize` returns the same function, `plot` takes it, `curve` does not. All these functions are from the base built-in R packages, so I expect them to cooperate and be consistent. Probably a bug?

Answer (score 3):

According to `?curve`

> expr - The name of a function, or a call or an expression written as a **function of x** which will evaluate to an object of the same length as x.

```
curve(Vectorize(lm_F_p_value)(x), col = "red", lwd = 3, lty = 2, 
       add = TRUE, ylab = "y")
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but why is `curve` so inconsistent with `plot.function` and requires the parameter to be called `x`, when `plot.function` doesn't?

Comment: @Tomas those are two different functions with different requirements - `plot.default`, takes a vector of 'x', 'y' as arguments where as `curve` takes expression.  I am not sure why the function was created in that way though

Comment: but this isn't `plot.default`, this is `plot.function`, see `?plot.function`. Yeah. I'm trying to figure out if there's any meaning behind it or perhaps just a design flaw (to be fixed :-)).

Comment: Just as a btw: it does not necessarily have to be a function of `x`. there is the `xname` parameter that takes in the parameter to be used. eg: `curve(Vectorize(lm_F_p_value)(new_Y1), xname = 'new_Y1')` would work

Comment: `plot.function` uses standard evaluation.  `curve` uses non-standard evaluation, trying to guess what you meant from the way you said it, not relying on the value of what you said.